# JSON string pulled via net/http to Hash

Tags: json, ruby, hash

I'm trying to pull JSON from a Yahoo API to get the conversion rate of USD to SEK. However, I can't seem to get the JSON converted to a Hash, it shows "query" as being the only key since JSON comes in as one string.

The JSON request returns:

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-12-04T13:06:00Z","lang":"en-us","results":{"rate":{"id":"USDSEK","Name":"USD/SEK","Rate":"9.1900","Date":"12/2/2016","Time":"9:59pm","Ask":"9.2000","Bid":"9.1900"}}}}
```

My code is as follow:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDSEK%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback='

uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
json_hash= JSON.parse(response)

puts json_hash["Rate"]
```

the puts statement returns 'nil'

I've tried following an example from [this site](http://www.jefferydurand.com/ruby/rails/json/oop/tips/tricks/2014/11/19/convert-json-to-useful-ruby-object.html), however I do not yield the same results based on the way my data is being brought as his is being statically entered.
 *Note I am not using 'ostruct', trying simply with json.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the field you are looking for is into an inner hash. Try

```
puts json_hash["query"]["results"]["rate"]["Rate"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the structure of your `json`?

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2016-12-04T13:06:00Z",
        "lang": "en-us",
        "results": {
            "rate": {
                "id": "USDSEK",
                "Name": "USD/SEK",
                "Rate": "9.1900",
                "Date": "12/2/2016",
                "Time": "9:59pm",
                "Ask": "9.2000",
                "Bid": "9.1900"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To fetch the `rate` key you should do something like:

```
json_hash["query"]["results"]["rate"]
```

Compare that with json above to understand your problem.